# XCode error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/anonym/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist'"

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase

With XCode i copied the GoogleService-Info.plist in the Runner folder, closed XCode and delete GoogleService-Info.plist from the downloads folder.
Now XCode is unable to build the application because the GoogleService-Info.plist is not in the download folder?

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. here is what i did.
I copied the file in runner without XCode then I open xcode and I drag the file again, massaging to check the copy item if needed box.

Then I do a clear then I launch the application and it works for me.

Answer (score 14):

Right click on the Runner -> select add files to runner -> select the Googleservices-info.plist file.

Make sure the copy files if needed is checked that way it copies the file from downloads folder to the project. Now you can close Xcode and delete the file from Downloads folder.

Go to product -> clean build folder.

Then run pod install once and build the project. It should work as expected.

[image: preview]

Answer (score 3):

open your

```
ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

file and find the line with

```
... GoogleService-Info.plist ...
```

in the same line it should say something along the line of

```
 path = "/Users/anonym/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

change it to the relativ path of your GoogleService-Info.plist file. In my case that was:

```
 path = "Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that referencing to the GoogleService-Info.plist file which is not in download folder. Please follow this to add it correctly for iOS https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-correctly-adding-googleservices-info-plist-to-ios/

Comment: Did not worked either, i have to set option "Copy items if needed", no it works. Anyway thank you!